# Viewing the next section of ActiveRecord responses in ruby console

Tags: ruby, activerecord, console

When you run a query in ruby console and you get more results than it wants to display at the same time, it shows

```
". . .]>"
```

to suggest there are more results.  Isn't there a key or command to show the next page or section of results?  I've been browsing but can't find the right term.

Comment: the down arrow maybe?

Comment: What query? What does mean “to display”? `puts`? Just `irb` output? `pry` output? Pagination?

Comment: I'm in ruby console, I run an SQL like User.all.  I have more users than can show on my little black square ruby gives me to work with.  After showing 10 or so, at the end of the list (where it cuts off), it just shows " . . .]>" to imply there is another page, but I forgot the command for how to get there.  The down arrow did not work :(